# Git: What is the fastest way to merge a working branch to master?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge, git-push

Suppose I was on `master` branch and created a new branch:

```
git checkout -b feature_branch
```

I started to work on `feature_branch`, and at some point I would like to merge my changes to `master` using rebase. So, I do:

```
# Get the latest code on master
git checkout master
git pull

# Rebase on master and push the most updated 'feature_branch'
git checkout feature_branch
git rebase master
git push

# Merge 'feature_branch' to 'master' and push the updated 'master'
git checkout master
git merge feature_branch
git push

# Back to work on 'feature_branch'
git checkout feature_branch
```

Is there a way to reduce the number of steps and achieve the same?

At the end of the process I would like `master`, `origin/master`, `feature_branch`, and `origin/feature_branch`, to point to the same commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a couple commands. This does the same:

```
# you have to have the branch checked out to pull, since pulling means merging
# into master, and you need a work tree to merge in
git checkout master
git pull

# no need to check out first; rebase does the right thing with two arguments
git rebase master feature_branch

git checkout master
git merge feature_branch

# git push by default pushes all branches that exist here and on the remote
git push

git checkout feature_branch
```

Strictly speaking, the merge into master is guaranteed to be a fast-forward (a trivial merge), so it doesn't actually need a work tree, but there's not really a built-in way skip the checkout. There are workarounds, e.g. pushing into the same repository: `git push . feature_branch:master` (safe, but weird) or directly updating the ref: `git update-ref master feature_branch` (unsafe - doesn't check if it's a fast-forward) but generally you might as well just quickly switch branches.

Also note that if you didn't want to rebase the feature branch, you could just skip that, not rewrite feature_branch, and end up with a merge commit in master instead of the rebased feature_branch and fast-forward merge.

Comment: Nice answer! Style thing but maybe "git pull . feature_branch" rather than "git merge feature_branch". And also might be cool to add a git push --tags

Comment: @AdrianCornish: `git pull . feature_branch` will do exactly the same thing as `git merge feature_branch`, only more confusingly. And I don't see anything here to indicate that tags need to be dealt with.

Comment: Agree - the tags was an extra feature maybe :-).
Agree the two commands are identical, the reason I suggested it is that the pull request workflow is used in a lot of OpenSource stuff - so that in effect you are responding to a pull request that you wrote. Purely a state of mind thing - you are pulling changes by Author X in Repo Y into your branch Z.